# Difference between two types of codes - modules

Tags: javascript, module

What is the difference between the two kinds of codes?
why is the first one is favorable over the second?

```
let mod1 = (function () {
    return {
      isCuteMixin: function(obj) {
        obj.isCute = _ => true;
      },
      singMixin: function(obj){ 
        obj.sing = _ => {console.log("Singing to an awesome tune");}
        }
    }
  })();

  let mod2 = {
    isCuteMixin: function(obj) {
        obj.isCute = _ => true;
      },
      singMixin: function(obj){ 
        obj.sing = _ => {console.log("Singing to an awesome tune");}
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is an Immeadiately Invoked Function that returns an object, the second one is an object.

Functions can have variables that can be accessed by all functions inside of it, and these variaboes can't be accessed from outside of the function. Therefore you can keep private variables related to a module with the first version.

---

That said nowadays I'd go with ES Modules instead:

```
   const privateVariable = "whatever";

   export function someMethod() { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: Is that the only advantage of the first method?